# how to handle java sql exception:exhausted result set

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

i have problem with the below code. help me!!

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","**********");
    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
    String sql="select password from db where username='user'";
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.next();
    String password=rs.getString("password");
    if(password.equals(pass))
    {       
        RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
        rd.forward(req,res);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("invalid username and password");
    }
```

when i execute this code i am getting an java sql exception : exhausted result set.    thanks in advance...

Comment: You're looking for a row with a username of `user` - you're never using the `user` variable. Therefore no rows are matching, therefore `rs.next()` returns false, but you're ignoring that and reading from the row anyway. (You should use parameterized SQL - but you also shouldn't be storing passwords in a database like this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using  `rs.next();`, use it with while e.g `while(rs.next())`. Once you got the resultset, the *pointer* will point to the first record. Each time you do a `rs.next()`, the  *pointer* will advances to the next record. If you use with while, once you reach to the end of your resultset, `rs.next()` will return false once all records are iterated. In your case, since you are not checking whether resultset has exhausted and trying to advanced the *pointer*, you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, because if you enter wrong username or password, NO record will be returned. So, when you use the `rs.next();` in this case, it is trying to access the first row of the empty result set

```
 String password=rs.getString("password");//error, if rs is empty
```

in the `where` clause you are not using `user` variable

`where` clause should be `where username='"+user+"'";`

and

instead of

```
rs.next();
```

use

```
if(rs.next())
{
     String password=rs.getString("password");
     ........
}
```